# SSRS group variables do not shown in expression editor window

Tags: sql-server, variables, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I just found that in SSRS the group variables do not shown in the "variables" category of expression editor Windows. So that means I can't double click the variable name to use them and I have to type them manually. I confirmed this issue on SSRS 2016 and 2008. Is this a bug or is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is by design but it's a well-known annoyance. There's no way to change this in the IDEs.